# AWS Codebuild fails while downloading source. Message: reference not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

A CI/CD pipeline that utilizes AWS Codebuild that has been functioning normally for months suddenly started failing when build's are triggered using a git tag as the source version. Builds triggered via pull request (pr/#) continue to work correctly. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What AWS region are you having this issue?

Comment: are you using the full tag or an abbreviated hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on the CodeBuild team.  We have rolled back a change that may have caused this behavior.  If you try your build again, it should succeed.

Comment: Hi Clare Liguori,

Just want to confirm is it possible to access cross account codemmit repo in codebuild.

We have given cross account codecommit repo access but on downloading phase it is giving error 

CLIENT_ERROR: git fetch failed with exit status 128 for source 74265c3d_a14e_48c2_ac29_1b318bbd3ca4