# AWS Codebuild fails while downloading source of tag from branch. Message: reference not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

A CI/CD pipeline that utilizes AWS CodeBuild suddenly started failing when build is triggered using a git tag as the source version that resides in a branch other than master. Manual "Retry" succeeds.

(similar to [AWS Codebuild fails while downloading source. Message: reference not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564672/aws-codebuild-fails-while-downloading-source-message-reference-not-found))

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the CodeBuild team.  Can you post this question on the [AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=230) for CodeBuild?  Then someone on the team can take a look at your builds and get more information to figure out why this failed.